# Match on start of number string

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching

I have some call charge codes that I need to match to telephone calls.

Example charge codes:

```
26481   Namibia - Mobile
26485   Namibia - Mobile
26482   Namibia-Mobile
441     National Call
442     National Call
674     Nauru
977     Nepal
97714   Nepal - Kathmandu
97715   Nepal - Kathmandu
```

Example call data:

```
442380010961
442380010961
441929555304
441929556253
448003163245
441305783009
447576883777
447576883777
441929554015
447434205058
447870133604
447434205058
442380436622
```

How can I using SQL match the start of the telephone numbers with the appropriate charge code?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: what is the data types? did you tried with like and % ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Case Expression with like & wild card in sql server. Follow these urls
* http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39103/A-Simple-Use-of-SQL-CASE-Expression
* http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Example

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN tb001 like 'code%' then 'place'
     WHEN tb001 like 'code%' then 'place'
     ELSE 'No CODE'
  END
  AS COLNAME
FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a really hard thing to do efficiently in SQL. You're probably working at a TelCo and have to match (dozens or hundreds of) millions of rows.

You might apply a LIKE-join plus ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT
     c.called_no
     ,p.pattern
     ,p.Destination_Tag
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.called_no ORDER BY p.pattern DESC) AS rn
   FROM
     CDRs c
   LEFT JOIN Prefixes p
     ON c.called_no LIKE p.pattern || '%'
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Or join on a SUBSTR:

```
SELECT
  c.called_no
  ,COALESCE(p12.Destination_Tag, p11.Destination_Tag, p10.Destination_Tag,
            p9.Destination_Tag, p8.Destination_Tag, p7.Destination_Tag,
            p6.Destination_Tag, p5.Destination_Tag, p4.Destination_Tag,
            p3.Destination_Tag, p2.Destination_Tag) AS tag
FROM
  CDRs c
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p12
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,12) = p12.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p11
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,11) = p11.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p10
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,10) = p10.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p9
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,9) = p9.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p8
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,8) = p8.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p7
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,7) = p7.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p6
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,6) = p6.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p5
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,5) = p5.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p4
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,4) = p4.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p3
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,3) = p3.pattern
    LEFT JOIN Prefixes p2
      ON SUBSTR(c.called_no,1,2) = p2.pattern
```

I was doing some performance tests on pattern matching a few years ago on a different DBMS with several variations of the above queries plus huge nested CASEs (several hundred KBs) automatically created using SQL.

Best performing was none of the SQL solutions, but a C-UDF :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the phone numbers are in numeric rather than string form. You can convert the numbers into strings and use `like` but that will be extremely inefficient as you would have to search the entire table, which looks like it could be quite large. There is one trick you could use:

```
WHERE call_num BETWEEN 264810000000 AND 264819999999 OR -- matches 1st Namibia - Mobile
      call_num BETWEEN 264820000000 AND 264829999999 OR -- matches 2nd Namibia - Mobile
      call_num BETWEEN 264850000000 AND 264859999999 OR -- matches 3rd Namibia - Mobile
      etc.
```

This allows for the use of index range scans so access will be limited to only those rows containing numbers of interest. Assuming, of course, that `call_num` is indexed.

There is also the old data modeling suggestion that data that happens to be numeric but which will never be used in mathematical operations, such as id, license, phone numbers and such, should be stored as strings. I have found this not to be a hard and fast rule, but in most instances can be advantageous. If the phone numbers were already in string format and indexed as such, you could use `call_num LIKE '26481%' OR call_num LIKE '26482%' OR...` with the same range scan efficiencies.